# Table rows won't stay same height after I set align to center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have the text block center to the video, but whenever I apply the align-items: center code, it makes it so that the rows become different heights. I've tried a lot of different solutions that haven't worked yet, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```css
.table-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;

}

.table-cell {
  padding: 2.5%;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%
}

.table-cell2 {
  padding: 2.5%;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 60%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .table,
  .table-row,
  .table-cell,
  .table-cell2{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <h2>What is Artek?</h2>
    <p>Merino Wool Blend 
<br><br>
This ultra-soft form fitting fabric used in our Puffy Jackets will keep you warm on any adventure. Its lightweight nature and its ability to pack down allows you to bring an extra layer anywhere without taking up too much space. But don't let its other features fool you, this fabric is more rugged than you'd expect.<br>
<br>
    <a href="/pages/product-materials#r-1574142479074">Learn more about Artek</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CM5Z21LMPA8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqhxk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a nested flexbox container to do your layout. The outer flexbox can stretch the items and the inner flexbox can align the items to the center. Remove `height: 100%` too. You may want to later adjust the code for different media queries. I have removed the `width: 100%` because it did not sound logical. I have also commented the codes for some quick explanation.

```css
.table-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; Removed so that the 2nd column does not go to different row */
}

.table-cell {
  padding: 2.5%;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex; /* Nested flexbox */
  align-items: center; /* Align nested items to center */
  flex-direction: column; /* Wrap them column wise */
}

.table-cell2 {
  padding: 2.5%;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <h2>What is Artek?</h2>
    <p>Merino Wool Blend 
<br><br>
This ultra-soft form fitting fabric used in our Puffy Jackets will keep you warm on any adventure. Its lightweight nature and its ability to pack down allows you to bring an extra layer anywhere without taking up too much space. But don't let its other features fool you, this fabric is more rugged than you'd expect.<br>
<br>
    <a href="/pages/product-materials#r-1574142479074">Learn more about Artek</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2">
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CM5Z21LMPA8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```